# Any source to list the trailers that showed before a particular movie?

Tags: trailers

I was searching for trailers that played before a movie I just saw, and landed on [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3736). While informative, I still haven't found a way to easily answer my question. Is there anyplace you can go to determine which trailers (are at least likely to) show before any given movie?

Comment: Is that not very much dependent on what the cinema itself will be scheduling in the future? Or are the previews actually always the same for a given movie?

Comment: @Flater There are some trailers that the studio requires to be shown, but the answers to the question I linked also stated that for digital exhibitions, there's actually no theater choice involved.

Comment: @close-voters If you simply pick "trivia" as a goto reason without bothering to explain why it's actually off-topic, I have no choice but vote to leave it open.